# R - Can't import CSV file - Column titles

Tags: r, csv

Im having problems importing a csv file because the tiltle line is like this: ",""date"",""revenue""". I tried a lot of things, but it keeps importing as 1 column, not as 3. Could you guys help me?

Comment: Can you post a sample of the csv file?

Comment: If you set `quote = ""` then `read.csv` will ignore the quotes, mismatched or not. You'll probably have to clean up the quotes in a followup step, but it will detect the three columns. (Assuming your header is literally what you posted, `",""date"",""revenue"""`)

Comment: I don't know if this helps in any form, but have you read the explanation of argument `quote` in the help page?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the code below from the readr package.

*Note: you will need to give df column names after importing.

```
readr::read_csv(file, col_names = FALSE) # need to remove the first row as well
```

or

```
readr::read_csv(file, skip = 1)
```